Reverse numerical list using Rmarkdown rendered to PDF with LaTex template
I would like to list my publications in reverse order on my CV, which I am generating using Rmarkdown and a LaTex template. In my searching I found the etaremune package but cannot figure out how to implement it for a particular section.
Is there a way to specify, in the template, that a particular header/section should use that package to print in the reverse order?
Example .RMD:
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
      keep_tex: TRUE
      template: test_latex-template.tex
---

# Full Name, PhD

## Education

University of Stack Exchange, 2020 

## Publications

3. Last, F, & Last F. (2024). Cool study. Cooler Journal.
2. Last, F, et al. (2023). Ok study. Ok Journal.
1. Last, F. (2020). Best study ever. Journal name.

## References
Some names and phone numbers

Example template:
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
$body$
\end{document}

These give me:


include the package in the template and the list environment in the document as raw latex code (see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-latex.html)

Another option without using latex packages is to insert HTML comments <!-- whatever --> between and separated by blank lines, i. e, make lists of single items, so the drawback is that numbers are not recalculated if you add some item before .

I found two workable solutions - the first thanks to @Fran's first comment:
1. Use raw latex to for the publications section. I think this is a little harder to read in the .rmd than the markdown syntax but that is just because of my own inexperience with latex.
I added
\usepackage{etaremune} to the template and then after ## Publications I have:
```{=latex}
\begin{etaremune}
\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\item
   Last, F, \& Last F. (2024). Cool study. Cooler Journal.
\item
   Last, F, et al. (2023). Ok study. Ok Journal.
\item
   Last, F. (2020). Best study ever. Journal name.
\end{etaremune}
```

2. Use the .tex output to manually change the packaged used and recompile. This is more steps than just updating the .rmd and knitting but maybe doesn't require knowing as much latex to get extra formatting just the way you want. it also requires adding \usepackage{etaremune} to the template.

Because of keep_tex: TRUE in the yaml, when you knit the .pdf will be created but so will a .tex file.
Open the .tex output and navigate to the 'Publications' section and find where it starts with \begin{enumerate} and ends with \end{enumerate}
Replace each instance of enumerate with etaremune
Hit Compile PDF at the top of the RStudio editor window. The PDF will be updated, and the order will be decreasing numerically.

